# How to reference a tag into an equation so that it looks like an argument

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, tags

what I am trying to do is referencing each part of the equation in a neat way, so that whenever the symbol is used one can know exactly what it stands for.
I would like to reference for use an equasion: 
`I_{(x)} = I_0*e^{\mu x}` but with all of this arguments being references from list of symbols

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,leqno,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\reqnomode
\begin{gather}
\eqref{eq:Ix}= \eqref{eq:I0}\eqref{eq:e}^{-\eqref{eq:mu} \eqref{eq:x}}  
\end{gather}
%works but the parenthesis..
%\begin{gather}
%\ref{eq:Ix}= \ref{eq:I0}\ref{eq:e}^{-\ref{eq:mu} \ref{eq:x}}  
%\end{gather}
%! Missing \endgroup inserted.

\leqnomode
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{itemize}[label=]
    \leftskip=1cm
    \item \begin{equation}
    \tag*{$I_{(x)}$}\label{eq:Ix} \textnormal{: text1}
\end{equation}
    \item \begin{equation}
    \tag*{$I_0$}\label{eq:I0} \textnormal{: text2 }
\end{equation}
    \item \begin{equation}
    \tag*{$e$}\label{eq:e} \textnormal{: text3}
\end{equation}
    \item \begin{equation}
    \tag*{$\mu$}\label{eq:mu} \textnormal{: text4}
\end{equation}
    \item \begin{equation}
    \tag*{$x$}\label{eq:x} \textnormal{: text5}
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you want but `\eqref{}` inserts automatically `()` while `\ref{}` does not.

Comment: With `\label{mylabel}`, you define the label. In a text, you can refer to the label with `\ref{mylabel}`. (If that is what you are asking.)

Comment: what i am asking is how to reference something that looks scientific like I_(x) and put it to equasion.
in my case it allways crash when i wat to apply power

Comment: When you refer to an equation you refer to its number not its contents.

Comment: yes, but I want to make an equation made of references to tags/symbols from another place with definition.
it works with \egref but the parenthesis are nasty

Comment: if you compile you will know what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, then you want to be able to define notation somewhere in the document, say in a list of symbols table, and then use this notation, and create hyperlinks, later on with some command. Assuming that this is what you want the code below does this.

The list of symbols are defined inside a `ListOfSymbols` environment. The work is done by a `\Symbol` command that has the following syntax:

```
 \Symbol{ref}{symbol}{description}
```

Here, `ref` is the reference text that will be used later on to use this symbol, `symbol` is the actual symbol text and `description` is a description of the the symbol. For example,

```
\Symbol{I0}{I_0}{Initial current}
```

gives the first line of the "list of symbols" table below.

The list of symbols table has three columns, giving the symbol, description and the first page of the document where the symbols is used. For example, the MWE below produces:

[image]

Later in the document the symbol, together with a hyperlink back to the list of symbols table, can be added using the `\sref` command. For example, the image below was made by typing `\sref{I0}` into the document, which then displays `$I_0$` together with a hyperlink as a mouse-over (well, this depends on your choice of PDF browser...acrobat is not smart enough to do this but skim, for example, is!):

[image]

Here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only needed for random text in MWE

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Symbol[3]{% \Symbol{reference}{symbol}{description}
   \csgdef{sym@#1}{#2}% define \sym@#1 to be the symbol text 
   % add line to list of symbols table
   \hypertarget{sym@#1}{$#2$} & #3 & \pageref{sym@page@#1}\\
}
\newcommand\sref[1]{% usage: \sref{reference}
  % add symbol with hyperlink
  \hyperlink{sym@#1}{\csuse{sym@#1}}% print symbol
  % create a link if this is the first time symbol is used
  \ifcsdef{sym@first@#1}{}%
     {\phantomsection\label{sym@page@#1}\csgdef{sym@first@#1}{\relax}}%
}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{ListOfSymbols}{% list of symbols environment
  % this is really just a wrapper around a long table environment, 
  % which is used because the list of symbols may run over many pages
  \longtable{@{}lp{0.8\textwidth}r}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{List of symbols}
  \endhead\\
  }{\endlongtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{ListOfSymbols}
  \Symbol{I0}{I_0}{Initial current}
  \Symbol{Ix}{I_x}{Current at $x$}
  \Symbol{mu}{\mu}{Flux}
\end{ListOfSymbols}

\lipsum% some random text to get a page break

\[
     \sref{Ix} = \sref{I0}e^{\sref{mu}}.
\]

We can use $\sref{Ix}$ again.

\lipsum

and again $\sref{Ix}$...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

What follows is a some kind of dirty trick and might cause some layout-troubles. The following runs with `pdfLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,leqno,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnomode}{\tagsleft@true}
\newcommand{\reqnomode}{\tagsleft@false}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\mref}[1]{\textup{\ref{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\reqnomode

\begin{align}
    \mref{eq:Ix}
        &= \mref{eq:x}\mref{eq:I0}\mref{eq:e}^{-\mref{eq:mu} \mref{eq:x}}  \\
    \eqref{eq:Ix}
        &= \eqref{eq:x}\eqref{eq:I0}\eqref{eq:e}^{-\eqref{eq:mu} \eqref{eq:x}}\\
    \textup{\TeX}
        &\neq\mref{eq:x}\frac 1 {\mref{eq:x} \frac 1 {\mref{eq:x} \frac 1 {\mref{eq:x}\frac 1 {\mref{eq:x}}}}}
\end{align}

%works but the parenthesis..
\begin{gather}
    \mref{eq:Ix}= \mref{eq:I0}\mref{eq:e}^{-\mref{eq:mu} \mref{eq:x}}  
\end{gather}
%! Missing \endgroup inserted.

\leqnomode
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{itemize}[label=]
    \leftskip=1cm
    \item \begin{equation}
    \tag*{$I_{(x)}$}\label{eq:Ix}\textnormal{: text1}
\end{equation}
    \item \begin{equation}
    \tag*{$I_0$}\label{eq:I0} \textnormal{: text2 }
\end{equation}
    \item \begin{equation}
    \tag*{$e$}\label{eq:e} \textnormal{: text3}
\end{equation}
    \item \begin{equation}
    \tag*{$\mu$}\label{eq:mu} \textnormal{: text4}
\end{equation}
    \item \begin{equation}
    \tag*{$x$}\label{eq:x} \textnormal{: text5}
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I think I understood your question: You want to define a list of symbols and you want to make sure that a change in the list changes all symbols in the text. An **alternative** would be a direct command for each symbol with `\newcommand` or `\DeclareMathOperator` and so on. This is what I usually do.